# How to rename directory with WinSCP .NET assembly?

Tags: vb.net, winscp, winscp-net

I want to be able to rename directory whether it contains something or not. I do not see such option. For instance this is how I create directory, but how to rename it?:

```
Public Sub CreateDirectory(path As String)
    If session IsNot Nothing Then
        session.CreateDirectory(path)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Session.MoveFile` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_movefile):

```
session.MoveFile("/path/directory", "/path/new_name")
```